# Spring Security custom accessDeniedHandler is ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to create a `Spring Boot` app that will serve as a back-end service provider for angular/mobile apps. When a user makes a request that he/she is not allowed to do, user has to get a response like "*forbidden*" for example.
I've created an `@EnableWebSecurity` annotated class that overrides `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. I have tried the following:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/test.txt").authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedHandler((HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) -> {
        response.sendError(403, "forbidden");
    });
```

And even this didn't work

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/test.txt").authenticated()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/somepage");
```

What I get is `403` response with *html* text as follows:

```
"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, 
 so you are seeing this as a fallback. 
 There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). 
 Access Denied"
```

I've already googled for the answer and got advises to create a `@ControllerAdvice` class to catch `AccessDeniedException`s.

But, first, I already have such class that has `@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)` annotated method (to catch all possible exceptions in an application) and it is not invoked either, second, I would like to understand why my first method doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `sendError` use `setStatus` . a `@ControllerAdvice` won't work as the exception happens in the filter chain not inside the `DispatcherServlet`. Next to that make sure you are following the correct rules regarding security overrides in Spring Boot (see the reference guide for that).

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks, but it didn't help. I tried                     'response.setStatus(403);'
'response.getWriter().print("forbidden");', it is still giving a spring error page. I think I configured it well, since it is at least blocking access to test.txt for unauthenticated users.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I've found an answer for my questions. The thing is Spring security first tries to authorize the user and calls for authenticationEntryPoint, and only if user is authorized already and access is still denied, it will call for accessDeniedHandler. In my case it was trying to find authenticationEntryPoint and giving an error. Thank you anyway!